# Linux kernel meta package and headers

Tags: kernel, updates

Running Xubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

What is the idea and what is the difference between Linux Kernel, Linux header and meta packages ? What if I have one with updated version and one with previous ? And why does Ubuntu update them often compared to Linux Mint (LM). I feel like I am beta testing - kernel updates are between 60 to 100 MB. I installed Xubuntu less than a month ago - since them I have updated the kernel 3 times as far as I can remember. Two days ago I updated the kernel - today I have something called Linux kernel for development 3.13.0.59.98->3.13.0.61.100

Please, explain to me. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Linux image packages contain linux kernels. Sometimes part of image is located in a separate `linux-image-extra` package.

Linux headers are needed to compile additional kernel modules for a specific kernel. Additional modules may be some drivers, virtualbox, etc.

Meta packages are for automated kernel upgrades. E.g `linux-image-generic` points to the latest available linux image.

`linux-generic` points to `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`.

For Ubuntu LTS versions there are multiple meta packages pointing to different major kernel versions.

**For 14.04:**

`linux-generic` downloads kernel 3.13

`linux-generic-lts-utopic` -> 3.16

`linux-generic-lts-vivid` -> 3.19

Ubuntu boots always with the latest kernel image unless it is intentionally changed in grub settings. If you have headers of an older version, they will not be used.

Linux Mint uses the same repositories as Ubuntu and kernel upgrades are exactly at the same time in Mint and Ubuntu.

Kernel 3.13 was upgraded many times lately because there were some bugs there.

Comment: As I said, you are a kernel hacker :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the explanation. However, I'd appreciate if you or someone else clarifies some things:

"What if I have one with updated version and one with previous ? " meaning if I update the kernel only but not the headers ?

I am now with LTS 14.04.2 and the kernel is already on 3.16 series - then why I do need to update whatever stuff for 3.13 if I already have 3.13. Now Xubuntu wants me to update "Linux Kernel Header for Developments" -> 3.13.0.59.98->3.13.0.61.100 . So why if I already have several 3.16 kernels ?

Comment: I already explained that. Headers not matching the running kernel will not be used. You can see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/654954/167850) how to stop 3.13 kernel updates.