# Kernel advice and how to block unwanted downloads

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

Further to the question/comment “WINE FAILURE today”:

The upgrade to kernel 3.13-59 was problematic. Following advice I upgraded my kernel to 3.19-25 which overcame my problem. Shortly afterwards version 3.13-61 was released (kudos to those involved for their speed – “everyone has problems, the important thing is the way they are dealt with”), that too cures my problem. I am currently running 2.19-25 but I am also getting upgrades in the 3.13 series.

Given that my main requirement is for a system as stable as possible, am I better to stay with 3.19 or revert to 3.13?

Further, I assume I will keep getting upgrades to both the 32.13 and 3.19 series. How do I stop the “unwanted” ones being downloaded? (I'm relatively new to this game, please be as explicit as possible.)

Thanks for any help

Comment: 3.19 is quite stable. Which is "unwanted"? 3.13 or 3.19?

Comment: Given (a)  that 3.19 is as stable as 3.13 (and presumably is more "advanced") and (b) upgrades in the 3.19 series will be downloaded and installed I  do not want to get upgrades in the 3.13 series downloaded. I know how to get rid of the versions already on my machine (using Ubuntu Tweak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop installing 3.13 upgrades you can run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You can also install Synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and remove linux image and headers packages of version 3.13, that may not be removed at the previous step.